# how to check for certain extensions in php

Tags: php

I want to filter some extensions. 
I have this variable which gets me the extensions of files in a folder:

```
$Extension = pathinfo($file, PATHINFO_EXTENSION);
```

Now i want to filter some extensions to view; i made a variable of it:

```
$ViewFiles =  array('jpg', 'png', 'gif', 'pdf', 'html');
```

If the extension is one of the $ViewFiles; show a view icon:
I tried that to achieve by this but it doesnt work:

```
if($Extension == $ViewFiles) {
// echo view icon
}
else {
// dont echo view icon
}
```

What is the correct way to do this?

Comment: what error are you getting? did you try echoing $Extension? What does $Extension echo to?

Comment: The echo of $Extension gives me as ouput: **gif** or **jpg** or **png** and so on...

Comment: Do you want to filter extensions or file types? (extensions are not reliable indicators of file types; certainly not if you're dealing with user input)

Comment: show us the code you are using to initiate $file

Comment: i prefer to filter on extension; i used to do it with mime_content_type but now i want to filter on extensions only

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You're nearly there. Try using the `in_array` function.

`if ( in_array( strtolower($Extension), $ViewFiles ) ) {
  // echo view icon
}`

Comment: Awesome! Now it works great! Thanks for this solution

Answer (score 2):

As an alternative to the `in_array()` solution you could use

```
$ViewFiles =  array(
        'jpg' => 'jpg',
        'png' => 'png',
        'gif' => 'gif',
        'pdf' => 'pdf',
        'html' => 'html');

if ( isset($ViewFiles[ $Extension ]) )
    // show view icon
```